# What is the purpose of this CanvasJS code line?

Tags: javascript, canvas, graph, canvasjs

I am using CanvasJS and always used these lines here:

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
   {
    ...
    });
    chart.render();
```

Unfortunately, I do not know what these lines are doing. Can someone explain it to me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 6):

### What are these lines doing??

Well on their own not much. In the context of a javascript engine a lot or not much.

#### The short version.

Creates and renders a CanvasJS.Chart, putting the chart in the DOM element identified as "chartContainer". Well it would if it was complete.

#### The long version.

- `var` is a javascript token. It is used to declare a variable and is usually followed by the name or variable identifier of the variable. In this case `chart`. You could also use the tokens `let`, `const`, or `function` (and some others) which have different scope and access to the contents of the variable they declare
- `=` is an assignment operator. It moves the data from the expression on the right to the variable/property on the left.
- `new` (javascript token)is a special token that modifies the way a function is called (In days of old when javascript was still considered a toy it was used to make javascript look hip and cool) It is rather superfulouse in the language so you can ignore it for now.
- `CanvasJS` (variable identifier) is a variable that was declared somewhere in the javascript code (hopefully) using one of the declaration tokens (most likely `function`). It has been capitalised which is significant. In Javascript when you capitalise a variable identifier you are telling the world that this is a special function that will always return an `Object` if called. It also tells you that it might have a special property called `prototype` which helps the javascript engine run your code a little quicker and helps you by simplifying your data structures using something called inheritance.
- `.Chart` (property identifier) This is a property, the dot "." between  `CanvasJS` and `Chart` signifies property of (called Dot notation, but could equally have been the not so popular,  Bracket notation `CanvasJS["Chart"]` same as `CanvasJs.Chart`. )

  So `Chart` is a property of `CanvasJS`. A property is like a variable but rather than being alone the property is attached to an Object. This is very handy for grouping related data and information

  Because `CanvasJS` has a big C, `Chart` is most likely (but not a certainty) one of the special prototype properties of `CanvasJS`.
- `(` Opening brace. When you see one of these after a variable identifier it means that the variable is a function that can be called. It at some point must have a closing brace `)` What is between `(` and `)` are called function parameters, or arguments and are passed to the function. There is a whole set of rules governing what goes between the ( and ) and way to much to cover now.

  Calling a function does a lot of special stuff, in the most basic terms the javascript engine locates that code that belongs to the function, packs its bags with arguments, goes to the function code, sets up camp, executes the function code and then returns with all the groover holiday shots. Anyways I digress
- `"chartContainer"` first argument, a string literal. It is abstractly a devoted bit of memory that holds a "string" of characters. Strings and string literals have many uses, but looking at the content of this string I can guess what it is used for.

  It is an identifier, name, or query used to find a DOM object (Document Object Model, the ugly bit hanging of the side of javascript, the dude whose party Javascript came to but nobody likes and wishes would go away) The bit of HTML that will hold the chart
- `,` comma used to separate arguments (in this case)
- `{` Opening curly or Object literal. Like the string literal but instead of characters it contains properties. needs to have a closing curly at some point
- `...` the dots by themselves in this context is just gibberish and will cause the javascript parser  to stop dead in its tracks and not look at anymore code. We know it's gibberish, so does javascript, but rules are rules so we need to clean this up.
- `//...` commented epsilon referring to the missing code.
- `}` closing object literal.
- `)` end of function's argument list.
- ; End of expression, like `new` it is not really needed but god (AKA Douglas Crockford) linted that it must be so, or you will be smittened by the obscure bugs and the taunts of JSLint and friend forever. (also you can not see return characters, so `;`  tells you this statement/expression/blockless code block, is complete.)

  At this point javascript will call the function `CanvasJs.Chart` passing the arguments, a string and an object. The function will do its thing and with luck will return a object (we know it will be an object because the `new` token and that `Chart` has a big C). The `=` will give the variable identified as `chart` (note the small c) a referance to the returned object.
- `chart.render()`  Property of referenced object held by `chart` called `render` is a function, call it with no arguments. I am guessing that it draws a chart and that chart can be seen in the DOM inside an element that may have the id `chartContainer`.

Comment: @Kaiido Holiday???... yes I had one of those once, I used it to catch up on some work.. :P No needed a break and got carried away.

Comment: @Kaiido 1.3million questions, does that include overly broad questions? always wondered what happens to questions that get booted, do they get counted, is not a tick in the ledger worth more than the item it represents, good or bad 1.3million and one more, kind of mocks the standards. What ever happened to my adverts, oh there in the sidebar. It is not the question that is being moderated away, it is the fear of a drop of blood that would tip a pack of wild bloodthirsty public forum junkies from nice to unmanageable. We answer all questions but dont feed the animals.